# How to make a script which always activates on the startup?

Tags: bash, scripts, paths

So I'd like to add always a folder to the Path. I'm not a huge linux wizard but I think I would need to always write the "export PATH=$PATH:(directory)" line when I log in. But I need this to be on when I'm starting up, and I don't want to bother with Terminal everytime.
So looking into it a little, I found that i should add that to .bash_profile even though I'm not sure what it is or where it's located. In the home directory there's only a .bashrc file.
Hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: Make a script and add it to startup applications, it will fire up every time you start your computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Add path to variable $PATH

As your comment says... you are running Lubuntu. Then to add a new Path to your $PATH you can try this:

**1)** Open a Terminal and type:

- `gksudo leafpad /etc/environment`

*(The /etc/environment file contains variables specifying the basic environment for all processes)*

[image]

**2)** In my case I added the path **:/home/user/bin** after **/usr/local/games**

[image]

So the content of my PATH is:

- `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/user/bin"`

**3)** Then just logout and login to see the changes.

### Add script to startup

**1)** Open a Terminal and type.

- `gksudo leafpad /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`

Then you can add a command.

My case is "test" script: **@bash /home/virtual/Desktop/test**

[image]

**2)** Then just logout and login to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look under System > Preferences > Startup Applications.
Be sure you mention the path correctly, provide a name and description for the script.

That should do it.

Comment: I doesn't seem to find it. I'm using Lubuntu. I pressed the "start menu" and from there "Preferences" but from there, there's no trace of Startup Applications